# Handle property change event listeners (lots of them) more elegantly (dictionary?)

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

hELLO !

Here i have a simple class example with three fields of type class B and some other stuff.
As you can see im listening on every child object change.
Since i could need alot of properties of type class B i wonder if there is a way of shrinking the code. Creating a listener + a method for each seems like i will have ALOT of code. How would i fix this ... using a dictionary or something similar? I have been told that IoC could fix this, but im not sure where to start.

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (_id == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id"); 
        }
    }

    public string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _name = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Name"); 
        }
    }

    public B _firstB;
    public B FirstB
    {
        get { return _firstB; }
        set 
        {
            if (_firstB == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (_firstB != null)
            {
                FirstB.PropertyChanged -= firstObjectB_Listener;
            }

            _firstB = value;

            if (_firstB != null) 
                FirstB.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(firstObjectB_Listener);

            OnPropertyChanged("FirstB"); 
        }
    }

    public B _secondB;
    public B SecondB
    {
        get { return _secondB; }
        set
        {
            if (_secondB == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (_secondB != null)
            {
                FirstB.PropertyChanged -= secondObjectB_Listener;
            }

            _secondB = value;

            if (_secondB != null)
                SecondB.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(secondObjectB_Listener);

            OnPropertyChanged("FirstB");
        }
    }

    public B _thirdB;
    public B ThirdB
    {
        get { return _thirdB; }
        set
        {
            if (_thirdB == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (_thirdB != null)
            {
                ThirdB.PropertyChanged -= thirdObjectB_Listener;
            }

            _thirdB = value;

            if (_thirdB != null)
                ThirdB.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(thirdObjectB_Listener);

            OnPropertyChanged("ThirdB");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    void firstObjectB_Listener(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Object A has found a change of " + e.PropertyName + " on first object B");
    }

    void secondObjectB_Listener(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Object A has found a change of " + e.PropertyName + " on second object B");
    }

    void thirdObjectB_Listener(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Object A has found a change of " + e.PropertyName + " on third object B");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant way I know of is to use Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) with a tool such as [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). I found INotifyPropertyChanged implementation examples [here](http://ruskin-dantra.blogspot.com/2009/03/inotifypropertychanged-made-easier.html) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/propfu/). These allow you to decorate your properties with an attribute and PostSharp then implements INotifyPropertyChanged for you when the code is built.

Comment: I have been looking into PostSharp alot. The problem is that i cannot get child property change chain to work in it. Maybe there is some solution for PostSharp 2.0, but we are using PostSharp 1.5 and the solutions do not work there. I can pack INotifyPropertyChange as an aspect allrite, but i cant figure out how to handle child changes (any level). Any idea?

Comment: I haven't actually used it. They do have a support forum (http://www.sharpcrafters.com/forum/) and I noticed that 1.5 is marked as "legacy" so you'll probably have to upgrade to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting up a dependency chain. None of the AOP or static analysis solutions are going to handle this properly. Check out Update Controls, which uses dependency tracking to [discover dependency chains at runtime](http://updatecontrols.net/doc/advanced/dependent-properties).

Here's what your example becomes:

```
public class B
{
    private Independent<string> _someProperty = new Independent<string>();

    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _someProperty; }
        set { _someProperty.Value = value; }
    }
}

public class A
{
    private Dependent<string> _dependentProperty;

    public A()
    {
        _dependentProperty = new Dependent<string>(() =>
            FirstB.SomeProperty + ", " + SecondB.SomeProperty + ", " + ThirdB.SomeProperty);
    }

    public string DependentProperty
    {
        get { return _dependentProperty; }
    }

    private Independent<int> _id = new Independent<int>();
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id.Value = value; }
    }

    private Independent<string> _name = new Independent<string>();
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name.Value = value; }
    }

    private Independent<B> _firstB = new Independent<B>();
    public B FirstB
    {
        get { return _firstB; }
        set { _firstB.Value = value; }
    }

    private Independent<B> _secondB = new Independent<B>();
    public B SecondB
    {
        get { return _secondB; }
        set { _secondB.Value = value; }
    }

    private Independent<B> _thirdB = new Independent<B>();
    public B ThirdB
    {
        get { return _thirdB; }
        set { _thirdB.Value = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One nice way to simplify the setup of your properties can be found [here](http://monotorrent.blogspot.com/2009/12/yet-another-inotifypropertychanged-with_06.html).

Regarding to your cascading notifications: I'd guess that you could use the approach outlined above to handle the (un-)subscription of events for properties implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` there.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify at little bit you can do the following two things.

First, in the handler of the PropertyChanged the first parameter, sender, is the object that fired the event, at least if you have implmented the OnPropertyChanged in class B the same way as in class A. This means you only need one handler for all the B properties.

```
private void BValueListener(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Found change of {0} on object {1}", e.PropertyName, sender);
}
```

If you need to do know exactly which of the B properties did the sending you could do checks in the BValueListener method.

```
if (sender == FirstB) { /* Do special stuff here */ }
```

Having the same listener for all the B properties we can then move on to write the property setter like:

```
private B _thirdB;
public B ThirdB
{
  get { return _thirdB; }
  set {
    if (UpdateBValue(ref _thirdB, value)) {
      OnPropertyChanged("ThirdB");
    }
  }
}
private bool UpdateBValue(ref B value, B newValue)
{
  if (value == newValue)
  {
    return false;
  }

  if (value != null)
  {
    value.PropertyChanged -= BValueListener;
  }

  value = newValue;
  if (value != null)
  {
    value.PropertyChanged += BValueListener;
  }
  return true;
}
```

If you really need different handlers for each property you can modify the code above to something like

```
private B _thirdB;
public B ThirdB
{
    get { return _thirdB; }
    set 
    { 
        if (UpdateBValue(ref _thirdB, value, BValueListener))
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("ThirdB");
        }
    }
} 

private bool UpdateBValue(ref B value, B newValue, PropertyChangedEventHandler eventHandler)
{
    if (value == newValue)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (value != null)
    {
        value.PropertyChanged -= eventHandler;
    }

    value = newValue;

    if (value != null)
    {
        value.PropertyChanged += eventHandler;
    }
    return true;
}
```

where you can send in the listener method you would like to use in each case.

Comment: thanx for the anwser Robert. But i need to go a step further.
I need to create some sort of "helper" class that would handle events for my classes. My goal is to keep the classes clean as much as possible (perhaps even the INotifyPropertyChanged interface injected on demand). I have been reading about "TypeDescriptor" can do this, but to be honest im still in the dark...

Answer (score 0):

A tool you could consider is T4 (T4 is shipped with VS2010 so no additional dependencies needed).

T4 is a code-generation tool which can help reduce the maintainance of "tedious" code. Think ASP/PHP for code. It's also similar to XML/XSLT.

For an excellent introduction to T4 please see [Oleg Sychs](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/) blog.

The benefits of code-generation in a case like this is that even though the generated code is redundant the code that you maintain (the T4 template) isn't or at least is less redundant.

So thinking about the sample you provided I wrote this T4 template:
(If you would like to try this template in Visual Studio click Add New Item, chose class template but change the extension from .cs to .tt, paste the following source in the .tt file and save. After save the result should be in the corresponding .cs file)

```
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
// ReSharper disable PartialMethodWithSinglePart
// ReSharper disable PartialTypeWithSinglePart
<#
    // This is the "model" that is "what" we would like to generate
    var classDefs = new []
    {
        new ClassDefinition
        {
            Name = "A",
            Properties = new []
            {
                P ("int"    , "Id"      ),
                P ("string" , "Name"    ),
                P ("B"      , "FirstB"  , listenToChanges:true  ),
                P ("B"      , "SecondB" , listenToChanges:true  ),
                P ("B"      , "ThirdB"  , listenToChanges:true  ),
            },
        },
        new ClassDefinition
        {
            Name = "B",
            Properties = new []
            {
                P ("int"    , "Id"      ),
                P ("string" , "Name"    ),
            },
        },
    };
#>

namespace SO
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;

<#
    // This part is the template ie "how" the model will be transformed into code
    foreach (var classDef in classDefs)
    {
#>        

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>
    /// class <#=classDef.Name#> (implements INotifyPropertyChanged)
    /// </summary>
    public partial class <#=classDef.Name#> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged (string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) 
            {
                handler (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (name));
            }
        }

<#
        foreach (var propertyDef in classDef.Properties)
        {
#>

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets property <#=propertyDef.Name#> (<#=propertyDef.Type#>)
        /// </summary>
        public <#=propertyDef.Type#> <#=propertyDef.Name#>
        { 
            get { return <#=propertyDef.FieldName#>; } 
            set 
            { 
                if (<#=propertyDef.FieldName#> == value) 
                { 
                    return; 
                } 

<#
            if (propertyDef.ListenToChanges)
            {
#>
                if (<#=propertyDef.FieldName#> != null) 
                { 
                    <#=propertyDef.FieldName#>.PropertyChanged -= <#=propertyDef.ListenerName#>;
                } 

                <#=propertyDef.FieldName#> = value; 

                if (<#=propertyDef.FieldName#> != null)  
                {
                    <#=propertyDef.FieldName#>.PropertyChanged += <#=propertyDef.ListenerName#>; 
                }
<#
            }
            else
            {
#>
                <#=propertyDef.FieldName#> = value; 
<#
            }
#>

                <#=propertyDef.EventName#> ();
                OnPropertyChanged("<#=propertyDef.Name#>");  

            } 
        } 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        <#=propertyDef.Type#> <#=propertyDef.FieldName#>; 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        partial void <#=propertyDef.EventName#> ();
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
<#
            if (propertyDef.ListenToChanges)
            {
#>
        void <#=propertyDef.ListenerName#> (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (
                "Instance of <#=classDef.Name#> detected a change of <#=propertyDef.Name#>.{0}", 
                e.PropertyName
                );
            <#=propertyDef.EventName#> ();
        }
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
<#
            }
        }
#>
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
<#
    }
#>
}
<#+
    class ClassDefinition
    {
        public string Name;
        public PropertyDefinition[] Properties;
    }

    class PropertyDefinition
    {
        public string Type;
        public string Name;
        public bool ListenToChanges;

        public string FieldName 
        {
            get
            {
                return "_" + Name;
            }
        }

        public string ListenerName 
        {
            get
            {
                return Name + "_Listener";
            }
        }

        public string EventName 
        {
            get
            {
                return "Change_" + Name;
            }
        }
    }

    PropertyDefinition P (string type, string name, bool listenToChanges = false)
    {
        return new PropertyDefinition
            {
                Type = type ?? "<NO_TYPE>",
                Name = name ?? "<NO_NAME>",
                ListenToChanges = listenToChanges,
            };
    }
#>
```

Finally this produces this output:

```
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
// ReSharper disable PartialMethodWithSinglePart
// ReSharper disable PartialTypeWithSinglePart

namespace SO
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>
    /// class A (implements INotifyPropertyChanged)
    /// </summary>
    public partial class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged (string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) 
            {
                handler (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (name));
            }
        }


        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets property Id (int)
        /// </summary>
        public int Id
        { 
            get { return _Id; } 
            set 
            { 
                if (_Id == value) 
                { 
                    return; 
                } 

                _Id = value; 

                Change_Id ();
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");  

            } 
        } 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        int _Id; 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        partial void Change_Id ();
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets property Name (string)
        /// </summary>
        public string Name
        { 
            get { return _Name; } 
            set 
            { 
                if (_Name == value) 
                { 
                    return; 
                } 

                _Name = value; 

                Change_Name ();
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");  

            } 
        } 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        string _Name; 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        partial void Change_Name ();
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets property FirstB (B)
        /// </summary>
        public B FirstB
        { 
            get { return _FirstB; } 
            set 
            { 
                if (_FirstB == value) 
                { 
                    return; 
                } 

                if (_FirstB != null) 
                { 
                    _FirstB.PropertyChanged -= FirstB_Listener;
                } 

                _FirstB = value; 

                if (_FirstB != null)  
                {
                    _FirstB.PropertyChanged += FirstB_Listener; 
                }

                Change_FirstB ();
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstB");  

            } 
        } 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        B _FirstB; 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        partial void Change_FirstB ();
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        void FirstB_Listener (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (
                "Instance of A detected a change of FirstB.{0}", 
                e.PropertyName
                );
            Change_FirstB ();
        }
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets property SecondB (B)
        /// </summary>
        public B SecondB
        { 
            get { return _SecondB; } 
            set 
            { 
                if (_SecondB == value) 
                { 
                    return; 
                } 

                if (_SecondB != null) 
                { 
                    _SecondB.PropertyChanged -= SecondB_Listener;
                } 

                _SecondB = value; 

                if (_SecondB != null)  
                {
                    _SecondB.PropertyChanged += SecondB_Listener; 
                }

                Change_SecondB ();
                OnPropertyChanged("SecondB");  

            } 
        } 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        B _SecondB; 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        partial void Change_SecondB ();
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        void SecondB_Listener (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (
                "Instance of A detected a change of SecondB.{0}", 
                e.PropertyName
                );
            Change_SecondB ();
        }
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets property ThirdB (B)
        /// </summary>
        public B ThirdB
        { 
            get { return _ThirdB; } 
            set 
            { 
                if (_ThirdB == value) 
                { 
                    return; 
                } 

                if (_ThirdB != null) 
                { 
                    _ThirdB.PropertyChanged -= ThirdB_Listener;
                } 

                _ThirdB = value; 

                if (_ThirdB != null)  
                {
                    _ThirdB.PropertyChanged += ThirdB_Listener; 
                }

                Change_ThirdB ();
                OnPropertyChanged("ThirdB");  

            } 
        } 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        B _ThirdB; 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        partial void Change_ThirdB ();
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        void ThirdB_Listener (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (
                "Instance of A detected a change of ThirdB.{0}", 
                e.PropertyName
                );
            Change_ThirdB ();
        }
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>
    /// class B (implements INotifyPropertyChanged)
    /// </summary>
    public partial class B : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged (string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) 
            {
                handler (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (name));
            }
        }


        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets property Id (int)
        /// </summary>
        public int Id
        { 
            get { return _Id; } 
            set 
            { 
                if (_Id == value) 
                { 
                    return; 
                } 

                _Id = value; 

                Change_Id ();
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");  

            } 
        } 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        int _Id; 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        partial void Change_Id ();
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets property Name (string)
        /// </summary>
        public string Name
        { 
            get { return _Name; } 
            set 
            { 
                if (_Name == value) 
                { 
                    return; 
                } 

                _Name = value; 

                Change_Name ();
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");  

            } 
        } 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        string _Name; 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        partial void Change_Name ();
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: If you like the T4 to pickup the C# code and generate code from that this guy explored some possibilities to do so in VS: http://danielvaughan.orpius.com/post/MetaGen-A-project-metadata-generator-for-Visual-Studio-using-T4.aspx